# Не считается выражение 3 класса школы в Java

Tags: java

Почему в третьей строчке Тост выводит всегда значение равное нулю (т.е percentCorrect имеет значение 0 )???

mCountCorrect и mCountAnswear - это int переменные, например 2 и 3 (в отладчике смотрел - они приходят нормально), но на шаге вывода тоста percentCorrect всегда 0.

Пробовал просто подставить во вторую строку `int percentCorrect = 3*100;` - так показывает нормально. Почему?

```
  if (mCountAnswear==mQuestionsBank.length){
            int percentCorrect = (mCountCorrect/mCountAnswear)*100;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Результат - " +percentCorrect +" % правильных ответов",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mCountCorrect=0;
            mCountAnswear=0;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Целочисленное деление не имеет дробей, поэтому например `2 / 4 = 0.5` (это не целое число!) который усекается до целого числа 0. Можно попробовать считать так:

```
int x = a * 100 / b;
```

или приводить числа к `double`/`float`. Жуткий вариант:

```
int x = (int) (((double) a / (double) b) * 100);
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, помогло только так:
double percentCorrect = ((double)mCountCorrect/(double)mCountAnswear)*100;

Comment: достаточно привести к double одну переменную из двух, обе необязательно